# C# Reflection Vs. method Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, attributes

I am trying to create a Log4Net wrapper interface. The code for the Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlayGround
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void SetSource(string typeName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide Log "message" and/or "exception" data only
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <param name="memberName"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceLineNumber"></param>
    void Error(string message, Exception exception = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide Log "message" and/or "exception" data only
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <param name="memberName"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceLineNumber"></param>
    void Warn(string message, Exception exception = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide Log "message" and/or "exception" data only
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <param name="memberName"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceLineNumber"></param>
    void Debug(string message, Exception exception = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide Log "message" and/or "exception" data only
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <param name="memberName"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceLineNumber"></param>
    void Info(string message, Exception exception = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide Log "message" and/or "exception" data only
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <param name="memberName"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath"></param>
    /// <param name="sourceLineNumber"></param>
    void Fatal(string message, Exception exception = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = null,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);
    }
}
```

The implementation:

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PlayGround
{
    class Log4NetLogger : ILogger
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log4NetLogger));
        private static readonly bool isErrorEnabled = log.IsErrorEnabled;
        private static readonly bool isWarnEnabled = log.IsWarnEnabled;
        private static readonly bool isDebugEnabled = log.IsDebugEnabled;
        private static readonly bool isInfoEnabled = log.IsInfoEnabled;
        private static readonly bool isFatalEnabled = log.IsFatalEnabled;

    private string TypeName;

    public void SetSource(string typeName)
    {
        TypeName = typeName;
    }

    public void Error(string message, Exception Exception = null, string memberName = null, string sourceFilePath = null, int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        if (isErrorEnabled)
        {
            string Message = BuildSourceDetails(message, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);

            if (Exception != null)
            {
                Message += BuildExceptionMsg(Exception.Message);
            }

            log.Error(Message);
        }
    }

    public void Warn(string message, Exception Exception = null, string memberName = null, string sourceFilePath = null, int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        if (isWarnEnabled)
        {
            string Message = BuildSourceDetails(message, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);

            if (Exception != null)
            {
                Message += BuildExceptionMsg(Exception.Message);
            }

            log.Warn(Message);
        }
    }

    public void Debug(string message, Exception Exception = null, string memberName = null, string sourceFilePath = null, int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        if (isDebugEnabled)
        {
            string Message = BuildSourceDetails(message, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);

            if (Exception != null)
            {
                Message += BuildExceptionMsg(Exception.Message);
            }

            log.Debug(Message);
        }
    }

    public void Info(string message, Exception Exception = null, string memberName = null, string sourceFilePath = null, int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        if (isInfoEnabled)
        {
            string Message = BuildSourceDetails(message, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);

            if (Exception != null)
            {
                Message += BuildExceptionMsg(Exception.Message);
            }

            log.Info(Message);
        }
    }

    public void Fatal(string message, Exception Exception = null, string memberName = null, string sourceFilePath = null, int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        if (isFatalEnabled)
        {
            string Message = BuildSourceDetails(message, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);

            if (Exception != null)
            {
                Message += BuildExceptionMsg(Exception.Message);
            }

            log.Fatal(Message);
        }
    }

    private string BuildSourceDetails(string message, string memberName, string sourceFilePath, int sourceLineNumber)
    {
        return "[Class: " + TypeName + " Member: " + memberName + " Source: " + sourceFilePath + " Line: " + sourceLineNumber + "] [" + message + "]";
    }

        private string BuildExceptionMsg(string message)
        {
            return " [System Exception: " + message + "] ";
        }
    }
}
```

I believe from a performance point of view the code works based on the online research I have carried out.

The question being; instead of using Attributes within the interface, is there an approach using C# Reflection so that I can move the code for Logging to the concrete implementation only? This way the interface is more generic?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Not sure what really want. But if you desperately need to use reflection, the stacktrace (very slow) could always provide the same info.

Comment: @leppie: yes I am avoiding using stacktrace due to the performance concerns..

Comment: Guess you don't want a direct dependency on NLog in your calling code. Why don't you simply use Facade or Adaptor design pattern?

Comment: @Chirdeep Tomar: I am rather new to C#. Could you kindly provide examples? (so that I can grasp the ideas you mention).

Comment: @Guygar please check the answer below.

Comment: @Chirdeep Tomar: Yes I have seen it but I think it does not answer my original question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the two design patterns, I prefer adaptor. Essentially you are creating an interface that creates an abstraction over the underlying logging provider, Nlog or Serilog.

http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern

http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern

But I am sure this problem is already solved a million times before. Have a look at https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging.